# When did the Federation make first contact with the Cardassian Union?

Tags: star-trek

It can't have been later than 2347 (Setlik 3 massacre and beginning of Cardassian-Federation War) but is there any other reference to when the two governments made official first contact?

Comment: There's no main canon description of Federation first contact with the Cardassians. I'll have a goggle at Memory Beta

Comment: I always read "Cardassian" as "Kardashian", slightly different implications though :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no main canon description of the Federation's first *formal* contact with the Cardassian Union. They do encounter Cardassian individuals in *Star Trek: Enterprise* — a Cardassian Borg, and what appears to be a Cardassian body at the automated repair station in "Dead Stop" — but these obviously don't answer the question of first official contact.

There are some (conflicting) accounts in various Trek novels and comics.
Per [Memory Beta](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Cardassian_history#Conflicts_with_the_Federation):

> By some accounts, first contact between the Federation and the
>   Cardassian Union occurred circa 2321, on the human colony world of
>   Juhraya. (VOY - The Brave and the Bold, Book Two novella: [The Third
>   Artifact](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/The_Brave_and_the_Bold#Book_Two))
>
> This conflicts with [Day of the Vipers](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Day_of_the_Vipers), which states that the
>   Cardassians were already engaged in "pointless, unresolved conflicts"
>   with the Federation by 2318. This implies a first contact date
>   sometime before or during 2318.
>
> The first official talks between the Cardassians and the Federation
>   took place in 2327, however the Cardassians were using the talks as a
>   pretense to disrupt relations between the Federation and Legarans to
>   make Legara IV susceptible to annexation by the Cardassians.
>   Fortunately the plan was uncovered and the Federation placed extra
>   Starfleet protection around Legara. (TOS comic: "[Enter the Wolves](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Enter_the_Wolves)")